# how i can make an array from an object if there are nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I need a function that would make an array like this from an object:

```
let obj = {
           name: 'john',
  age: 25,
  some: {
    a: 5.5,
    b: 5,
    c: 'pls'
  }
}
 objectToArray(obj);
 // Outputs: [['name', 'john'], ['age', 25], ['some', [['a',5.5], ['b', 5], ['c','pls']]]]
```

**How exactly should I check if there is a nested object? Is the Object.entries () method a good fit?**

I think we need a function that will check whether the object is passed or not, if so, it will open it and make an array of it [key, property] using the Object.entries () method, if there is also an object, then it will call itself again and for it ...
Ps: i need to use only native javascript with recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We can recurse like this:**

1. Check if the object passed in is an object using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

   - If it is continue.
   - If not `return` whatever the value is.
2. Convert the object to it's entries using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
3. Iterate over each `[key, value]` pair using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

   - Recursively call `objectToArray` on the value. (Jump to `1.`)

**This is what that looks like:**

```js
const obj = { name: 'john', age: 25, some: { a: 5.5, b: 5, c: 'pls', }, };

function objectToArray(obj) {
  if (!(obj instanceof Object)) return obj;
  return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [key, objectToArray(value)]);
}

console.log(objectToArray(obj))
```

Comment: I didn't understand how instanceof works, but the solution is good! thanks

Comment: @Xsalay My bad, I'll make an edit to the post with a hopefully clearer explanation.

Comment: I understood thanks for the answer, sometimes what is written in the handbook, I cannot understand.